# Bookmarks with Unprocessed Commands from chemnum and chemmacros

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, chemmacros, chemnum

In my document, I have sections that contain chemmacros `\iupac{}` command with shorthands provided by chemmacros `|` as well as my own shorthand `=`. For some reason, these shorthands are printed in the bookmarks.
I also use chemnums `\cmpd{}` command, but instead of the number, the compounds label is printed in the bookmarks.

[image: Output in Foxit Reader]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{chemmacros,chemnum}
\newcommand{\nbh}{\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}} % new command for non-breaking hyphens since \mbox is problematic in \iupac
\NewChemIUPACShorthand{=}{\nbh}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{\iupac{2=(Phenyl|thio)oxazole}~(\cmpd{Ox-SPh})}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the content is printed correctly in the table of contents. I would like to have the same processed output for my bookmarks, though. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use `\texorpdfstring{❬TEXstring❭}{❬PDFstring❭}` macros from `hyperref`. In `PDFstring` you need to do two things:

- replace `\cmpd{...}` with `\cmpdplain{...}`;
- don't use `\iupac{...}`, plain text only (who needs hyphenation in PDF bookmarks, anyways:) ).

From [`chemnum`'s manual](http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/chemnum/chemnum_en.pdf#page=3):

> `\cmpdplain{❬id❭}`
>
> Reads a label and writes it expandably without formatting. It is not able to parse a list. Its sole purpose is usage in pdf strings (*cf.* `\texorpdfstring{❬TEX❭}{❬pdf string❭}`)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{chemmacros,chemnum}
\newcommand{\nbh}{\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}} % da \mbox in \iupac problematisch ist, neuer Befehl für non-breaking hyphens
\NewChemIUPACShorthand{=}{\nbh}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{
        \texorpdfstring{
            \iupac{2=(Phenyl|thio)oxazole}~(\cmpd{Ox-SPh})
        }{
            2-(Phenylthio)oxazole~(\cmpdplain{Ox-SPh})
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant! I tried to use the square brackets of `\subsection[]{}`, but I lost the bold numbers in the ToC if I only used `\cmpdplain`. `\texorpdfstring` avoids this problem. Nice!
Btw: The `\iupac` command was used to prevent longer compound names (which I didn't consider in the question) from being split in the wrong places (e.g. after a number).
This function is of course not needed in the bookmarks but might be needed in the ToC or section headings.

Comment: I'd like to add: If there is a compound with sub-labels, you can use `\submaincmpdplain{<main id>}{<sub id>}`, as `\cmpdplain` will not work with sub-labels. To just print the sub-label only use `\subcmpdplain{<main id>}{<sub id>}`.